# Bash to read lines from file and assign to variable with delimiter

Tags: bash

In bash script, how can I read the file line by line and assign to the variable with delimiter?

**example.txt** file contents:

```
string1
string2
string3
string4
```

**Expected output:**

`string1,string2,string3,string4`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently my answer below leaves a comma at the end of the line. A quick workaround is to use the following builtin in Unix:

```
paste -sd, example.txt
```

Where you use the paste program to concatenate all the lines into one and then add the string delimiter ','

---

Using the builtin commands in unix:

```
tr '\n' ',' < example.txt
```

This can be broken down as truncating all Newline widcards and inserting a comma delimiter instead.

Comment: this will returns `string1,string2,string3,string4,` , I don't want to have ',' after last string `string4`. how to get rid of it?

Comment: Oh darn. That's what happens when doing midnight programming XD. A quick workaround I can think of is doing "paste -sd, example.txt" instead, to use the paste program to merge all the lines to 1 and use the comma delimiter

Answer (score 0):

It should work:

```
#!/bin/bash
output=''
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    output=$output:",$line"
done < "$1"
echo $output
```

Give the file as argument

Comment: Minor tweaks: `output="$output,$line"` and `echo ${output#,}`.

Answer (score 0):

Other possible ways, just for fun:

```
mapfile -t a < example.txt
(IFS=,; echo "${a[*]}")
```

```
mapfile -t a < example.txt
foo=$(printf '%s' "${a[@]/%/,}")
echo "${foo%,}"
```

```
foo=$(<example.txt)
echo "${foo//$'\n'/,}"
```

```
{
    IFS= read -r foo
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        foo+=,$line
    done
} < example.txt

echo "$foo"
```

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g' example.txt
```